# Powershell select a single property as a raw type

Tags: powershell

I have a script that's supposed to create some folders if they don't already exist.

```
"a","b","c" `
    | select @{Name="path"; Expression={Join-Path "C:\temp" $_}} `
    | select -ExpandProperty path `
    | where { -Not (Test-Path $_)}
```

Is it possible to extract the string from Join-Path more elegantly that assigning it to a named property `path` in the new object and then using another select with -ExpandProperty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
"a","b","c" | %{ 
    Join-Path "C:\temp" $_ } | where { -not (Test-Path $_)}
```

Comment: I should look up on what does %{ } do

Comment: Sorry, I could have developed a bit. % is an alias for Foreach-object. So Basically for each element in array ("a","b","c"), we perform a join-path, and test it.